# Get combobox displayField and valueField value dinammicaly without firing select event directly

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, extjs5

In a combobox, if a particular condition is verified, on render, is displayed the value of the displayfield (string) of a particular item .

When I submit the form I want to send the value of the displayField and the valueField.

Problem: only when the select event is triggered directly in the combobox dropdown list I get the value of the valueField.

I need to get this value dynamically without making a direct selection in the combobox.

How to do this?

*In the fiddle that follows: see the diferent result on render and after select a item in combobox*

FIDDLE: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2165

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var toselect = 'Arizona';
combobox.setValue(toselect);
```

I guess that toselect should be 3, not 'Arizona'

Comment: Thanks JustAndrei. it's a simple solution and it works great. In my case, what is sent from the server is a string, but I think I can solve this.